# Creating a file is causing problem, the File.getPath() doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to create a back up file for an html file on a web server.

I want the backup to be in the same location as the existing file (it's a quick fix). I want to create the file using File file = new File(PathName);

```
public void backUpOldPage(String oldContent) throws IOException{
            // this.uri is a class variable with the path of the file to be backed up
    String fileName = new File(this.uri).getName();
    String pathName = new File(this.uri).getPath();
    System.out.println(pathName);
    String bckPath = pathName+"\\"+bckName;

    FileOutputStream fout;      

    try
    {
        // Open an output stream
        fout = new FileOutputStream (bckFile);
        fout.close();       
    }
    // Catches any error conditions
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println ("Unable to write to file");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

But if instead I was to set bckPath like this, it will work.

```
String bckPath = "C://dev/server/tomcat6/webapps/sample-site/index_sdjf---sd.html";
```

I am working on Windows, not sure if that makes a difference.

The result of String bckPath = pathName+"\"+bckName;
is bckPath = C:\dev\server\tomcat6\webapps\sample-site\filename.html - this doesn't result in a new file.

Comment: I don't understand this question... maybe I need more coffee? :) :)

Comment: Essentially how do I get File.getPath() to give me forward slashes rather than backslashes

Comment: Why you need forward slashes? If you really wanna do that and you know what and why are you doing, you can come up with customize class for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use File.pathSeparator, that way you dont need to worry what OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`File.getCanonicalPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) instead of plain `getPath()`. This helps if the orginal path is not fully specified.

Regarding slashes, / or \ or `File.pathSeparator` is not causing the problem, because they are all the same on Windows and Java. (And you do not define `bckFile` in your code, only `bckPath`. Also use `getCanonicalPath()` on the new created `bckPath`.)